# Selenium: Python cannot find element from elif

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using an if-elif condition. The elements can be found when they are on the first condition but Selenium just hangs and can't find the element when it is on the elif. Any idea ?

Here is the code I am using:

```
if (driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[contains(text, 'Hello Automation User')]"))):
    print ("Test Passed")
elif (driver.find_elements_by_class_name('error')):
    print ("Test Failed: Username and Password combination mismatch")
else:
    print("Test failed")
```

FYI I am using chromedriver

Comment: Your question is very vague; Could you elaborate?

Comment: not sure how else can I explain. the scenario is : I want to use two conditions using if and elif. When I use the right condition in first if, it gets the element and returns appropriate output but when I use any of the condition on elif with the corresponding values, element is not found. And browser just keeps hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than catch exceptions try it like this:

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[contains(text, 'Hello Automation User')]"))) > 0:
  # pass
elif len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('error')) > 0:
  # fail
else:
  # fail
```

Note that driver.find_elements_by_xpath returns an array so it's always truthy (the way you had it)

Answer (score 0):

since its an elif statment by that nature it wont run the statment if the previous if statment is true:
e.g

```
x = True

if x:
 print('if')
elif x:
 print('elif')

output:   'if'
```

Comment: I am talking about when the previous if is false and it should go to the elif one.

Answer (score 0):

If element is not present `webdriver` will throw `exception` so you should use Try..Except block to achieve this.Hope this help

```
try:
  if (driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//*[contains(text, 'Hello Automation User')]"))):
    print ("Test Passed")
except:
  if (driver.find_element_by_class_name('error')):
    print ("Test Failed: Username and Password combination mismatch")
else:
    print("Test Failed")
```

Comment: If both of your condition failed it should go to else.

Comment: the second condition should pass and give me the user-p/w combination fail but it just hangs there and never finishes executing. there is no error either.

Comment: @nkalam: You were using find_elements instead of find_element just try my updated code.

Comment: Weird isn't it.can you post the html of the error condition.

Comment: Please check if it is inside any iframe? If it is inside any iframe you need to switch iframe first to access the element.

Comment: here it is:

<div class="error">
            An error occurred when trying to setup an account<br>
            <b>Error Message:</b> Incorrect email/password combination
          </div>

the driver can find the element when I use it on first if instead of elif or except condition

Comment: not inside an iframe btw, flat html...very weird :(

Comment: I don't know why this happening to you.when I run the html on my pc it is giving me correct result.however your testing negative condition if you wish you can share URL to me kajal.kundu@gmail.com if you dont want to publish in public.

Comment: thanks a lot but it's actually an university project in local environment so URL wouldn't launch it anyway :(

Comment: you didn't need to include any package or anything for that,right ?